# How to cover all the inside elements of a div without specifying the height

Tags: jquery, css

How to handle the height of a div to covers all of the inside elements? The number of elements in my div is not specified in advance and it keeps changing, so how can I handle the height in my below example?

```
$('#item1').hover(function(){

 $("#spec1").stop(true).animate({height:'100px'}, 300);
},function(){
$("#spec1").stop(true).animate({height:'0px'}, 300);
})
```

In other words I dont know the exact height of my div to cover the inside elements; how can I handle this issue?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/6ZSkg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should capture every time the number of elements change, and then recalculate the height based on that.

```
$("#SomeContainer").change(function(){
   var newHeight = $("#SomeContainer").height();
   $("#spec1").height(newHeight);
 });
```

Comment: keep in mind though if anything is absolutely positioned it will not be taken into account.

Comment: This is very true! You could also take the absolute height, if it is hard coded and doesn't change, and then add that to newHeight.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    $('#item1').hover(function(){
    var height = $("#spec1").children().length * 20;

     $("#spec1").stop(true).animate({height:height}, 300);
     },function(){
     $("#spec1").stop(true).animate({height:'0px'}, 300);
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this

```
<div id='item1'>
   Item 1
 </div>
<div id='spec1'>
<div id="container">
    sepc 1
    <br/>
    sepc 2
    <br/>
    sepc 3
    <br/>
    sepc 4
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
  $('#item1').hover(function(){
      $("#spec1").stop(true).animate({height: $("#prova").height()+"px"}, 300);
  },function(){
     $("#spec1").stop(true).animate({height:'0px'}, 300);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the height to 100% in your `animate()` and it will change with the height of the div.

```
$('#item1').hover(function(){
    $("#spec1").stop(true).animate({height:'100%'}, 300);
},function(){
    $("#spec1").stop(true).animate({height:'0px'}, 300);
})
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yetti/Bx58u/2).

---

**UPDATED**

My original answer will only work if the parent element has a fixed height.

If you're not too attached to using `animate()` you can use `slideDown()`/`slideUp()` instead:

```
$('#item1').hover(function () {
    $("#spec1").stop(true).slideDown(300);
}, function () {
    $("#spec1").stop(true).slideUp(300);
})
```

The CSS for `#spec1` will also have to change slightly. Removing `height: 0` and using `display: none` will also hide the div until hovered over. You already had this commented out in your CSS, so I've just uncommented it:

```
#spec1 {
    background-color:red;
    width:120px;
    display:none;
    text-align: center;
    /*height:0px;*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I've updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yetti/Bx58u/).

Comment: ummm... nice! but the animation does not work for appearing the box! Did you notice that?What is the reason?

Comment: The reason why it's not animating the box (`#spec1`) is because animate() requires the element or parent to have a fixed height. I've updated my answer to use slideDown()/slideUp(), which gives the same effect and you don't need to calculate the height as well this way.